# Ember - Can't get RESTAdapter to load data

Tags: ember.js

I've been searching around for an answer to my problem for a day now and i can't resolve it. I've seen some related subjects here, but none of them have solved my problem.

I can't get the DS.RESTAdapter to work in my ember app. I get the following log in my console

```
Attempting URL transition to / ember.js:3285
Transition #1: Beginning validation for transition to users ember.js:3285
Transition #1: application: calling beforeModel hook ember.js:3285
Transition #1: application: resolving model ember.js:3285
Transition #1: application: calling afterModel hook ember.js:3285
Transition #1: application: validation succeeded, proceeding ember.js:3285
Transition #1: users: calling beforeModel hook ember.js:3285
Transition #1: users: resolving model ember.js:3285
Ember Debugger Active VM4904:161
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/ember2/api/users". jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
Transition #1: users: transition was aborted ember.js:3285
Transition #1: users: handling error: [object Object] ember.js:3285
Error while loading route: undefined 




window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});


App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: "ember2/api"
});



//User model
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});


//Router
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', {path: "/"});
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user');
    }
});




//The json response
{
  "users": (I have tried users and user)
  {
   "id": 1
   "title": "Learn Ember.js",
   "isCompleted": true
  }, 
  {
   "id": 2
   "title": "Learn Ember.js",
   "isCompleted": true
  }
}
```

If somebody could nudge me in the right direction i would appreciate it!

Side note: If i use a fixture everything works fine!

Found out what i was doing wrong.

The problem was my poorly formatted json response. Correct syntax is:

```
{
  "user": [
     {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Learn Ember.js",
    "is_completed": true
     },
     {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Learn Ember.js",
    "is_completed": true
     }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to point out for anyone else that hit's the question, it was that his property was an object, when it should have been an array.  Technically it's supposed to be plural as well.

#### Incorrect

```
{
  "users": {  /// <---- users should be an array
```

#### Correct

```
{
  "users": [
     {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Learn Ember.js",
      "is_completed": true
     },
     {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Learn Ember.js",
      "is_completed": true
     }
   ]
}
```

More examples can be found here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md